# How to create a sitemap for dynamic content in zf2?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, sitemap

I want to create a sitemap for my web application written in zend. One option is I go to some online sitemap generator site and create one static sitemap according to my url. But what about the dynamic urls, so I want to create a sitemap which changes dynamically. It should have different priority for different module and how to change the lastmodified parameter for a particular url. If anyone had done the same thing then please do share your work.

Comment: Zend Navigation has a Sitemap helper, maybe that will help -> https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/modules/zend.navigation.view.helper.sitemap.html#zend-navigation-view-helper-sitemap

Comment: @crisp Say I have a module names "Project" and I have created some projects within it. So How their urls will be added to the sitemap? Do u have some more example bcoz this documentation is not clear to me.

Comment: @crisp I added this code in my view file(.phtml file) 
$this->navigation()
      ->sitemap()
      ->setFormatOutput(true); 
echo $this->navigation()->sitemap(); 
and In my controller I have written this code 
$view = new ViewModel();
$view->setTerminal(true);   
$view->setTemplate('path to view file');
return $view;
but it is not displaying anything. Do I need to write some other code. When I checked the page source I found only this . 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"/>